# Merge two server.log file into one server.log in master machine

Tags: jmeter

Running distributed load using 1 master and 2 slave machine in Jmeter.

I want to merge the two jmeter-server.log file from the individual slave machine to master machine and create one. Is there any way we can do this ?

so the jmeter-server.log on the master machine should have all the data from jmeter-server.log(slave-1) and jmeter-server.log(slave-2)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "merge"?

- If it is just adding jmeter-server.log from the slave 2 to the end of the jmeter-server.log file from slave1 you can append them using [Windows `copy` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy) like `copy jmeter-server-from-slave-1.log + jmeter-server-from-slave-2.log combined log` or [Unix `cat` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) like `cat jmeter-server-from-slave-1.log jmeter-server-from-slave-2.log > combined.log`
- If you need to sort entries chronologically you can use sort command like `sort --key=10,15 jmeter-server-from-slave-1.log jmeter-server-from-slave-2.log > combined.log`
- There is a GUI-based tool called [Vigilog](https://www.onworks.net/software/app-vigilog?amp=0) (it's [free and open source](http://vigilog.sourceforge.net/)) which can merge log files

If you're talking about JMeter's [.jtl results files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) coming i.e. from [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) - you can use [Merge Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/))